# Почему access_token живет дольше чем должен

Tags: keycloak

Я указал время жизни токена 20 секунд в блокировке ключа, но токен остается действительным в течение 1 минуты. Как сделать так, чтобы токен имел определенное время жизни и истекал вовремя

[image: Настройки]